# why JBoss would destroy connection pool on an error?

Tags: java, sql-server, jboss

I have a web application running on JBoss 4.2.3 connecting to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database through JTDS 1.2.2 driver. The Datasource is setup to have minimum 10 connections in the pool. This is the ds file `jtds-ds.xml`: (I have replaced the real jndi name, server name, database name, user name and password).

```
<datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>MyDS</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://MyServer/MyDatabase;tds=8.0;lastupdatecount=true</connection-url>
        <driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <user-name>MyUserName</user-name>
        <password>MyPassword</password>

        <set-tx-query-timeout>true</set-tx-query-timeout>

       <!--
            sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool
        -->
        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>    

        <!-- Pooling Parameters -->
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>500</prepared-statement-cache-size> 
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size> 
        <max-pool-size>40000</max-pool-size>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

I run the *SQL Server Profiler*. After the JBoss starts in the *SQL Server Profiler*, I can see 10 database connections to the `MyDatabase` database from the web application . Whenever any user works on the web application, I can see it in *SQL Server Profiler*. Everything looks good.

I start a process which is a very long process and insert million of rows in database. The process inserts 1000 rows at a time i.e. it gets connection from pool, insert 1000 rows in database, then close connection. I can see it in *SQL Server Profiler* and it is working ok.

While the process was running I got a warning in the log file and I think it was because the connection was lost to the database server

```
2015-03-26 11:50:35,611 WARN  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool] Unable to fill pool 
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection timed out: connect)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:190)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:619)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.fillToMin(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:534)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Network ` IOException: Connection timed out: connect
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:385)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.<init>(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:182)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:172)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:304)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.<init>(SharedSocket.java:255)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.<init>(ConnectionJDBC2.java:310)
    ... 7 more
```

After this error, the *SQL Server Profiler* is not showing any connections for the web application. JBoss is still running. Why JBoss would destroy its connection pool in this case?

### UPDATE:

When another user's request comes in the web application, I saw the *SQL Server Profiler* shows me 4 connections by the web application. So it is at least start building the connection pool again although I would expect it to show 10 connections.

My question still is that when such an error occurs (Connection timed out), why JBoss drop the whole 10 connections in the connection pool? The process was using only 1 connection, the other 9 connections were not being used as there was nobody else using the web application when the process was run. Also is it possible for JBoss to rebuild its connection pool by itself when it was somehow destroyed? I thought `check-valid-connection-sql` tag does that trick?

Comment: Are you sure your process is not misshandling the exception (that it does not attempt again to connect to the server)?

Comment: There is no database communication from the web application which means the process has crapped out